# Sublime Text regex to find all lines containing dump that do not start with //

Tags: sublimetext

I am using Sublime Text 3.

Using the ST3 Find dialog, I am trying to work out the regex that will find all lines that contain the string `dump` but that do **not** start with `//`. ie uncommented dump statements.

ie find these:

```
debugDump(recs);
dump(recs);
writedump(recs);
```

but not these:

```
//debugDump(recs);
//dump(recs);
//writedump(recs);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
 ^(?!^\s*\/\/).*dump
```

should find all matches without `//` at the start of line or any space characters before

And if your editor should have options:

```
 /^(?!^\s*\/\/).*dump/igm
```

In SublimeText 2 will work with: `(^\s*(?![\/]{2}).*(?:dump)` dunno about Sublime 3 :)

Comment: Thanks. I got an unmatched parenthesis error so I changed it to  `^\s*(?![\/]{2}).*(?:dump)` which might not be right either. It is finding any line with 'dump' in it but it is also finding those that DO have // at the start. ie includes those that are commented out.

Comment: so this is `(^\s*(?![\/]{2}).*(?:dump)` not working for you? can you please give me samples.

Comment: No. As I said it throws an error message "Unmatch marking parenthesis" ... while parsing fragment `.*(?:dump)`. I tried this `(^\s*(?![\/]{2}).*(?:dump))` and this `(^\s*(?![\/]{2})).*(?:dump)` which makes the error go away. However, it finds lines like `//writeDump(userPersonRec);` and `//debugDump(userPersonRec,"userPersonRec");` as well as `writeDump(userPersonRec);`.

Comment: It work like a magic: http://i.imgur.com/xr4RNWT.png it is sublime text 3 version

Comment: Try this ... `(^\s*(?![\\\\/]{2}).*(?:dump))` maybe this will not cause error

Comment: Thanks for your help Alexander, I really appreciate it. The problem is that I was ambiguous in my original question. When I said "at the start of the line" I really meant "is the line commented out" irrespective of whether the // starts in column 1. So, both your suggestions do work (once the parentheses are balanced) but only if the // is at position 1 in the line. See [http://www.murrah.com.au/test/st3find.jpg](http://www.murrah.com.au/test/st3find.jpg). My aplogies for not being more accurate in the first place. So, in the example, only the first 3 uncommented items should be found.

Comment: `^(?!^\s*\/\/).*dump` I hope it will help for your case

Comment: Brilliant!! Thank you so much Alexander.